# An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll Additional information: Unexpected error. Unknown error

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am creating a very simple console application to essentially show that I have setup the web driver correctly before moving on to more advanced applications. I am using C# with the selenium language bindings and Microsoft Edge.

I have version 3.0 of the Selenium Web Driver C# language bindings listed [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver).

I have Microsoft Edge version 38.14393.0.0 with Microsoft EdgeHTML 14.14393

I am on Windows 10 Anniversary edition (14393 Build 1607) and have the corresponding version of the Micrsoft Web Driver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

I am testing in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015

When I try to initialize the EdgeDriver I get this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Unexpected error. Unknown error
```

It is throwing the exception on this line of code:

```
  static IWebDriver Edge = new EdgeDriver();
```

I would like ways of troubleshooting this or if I have some kind of version mismatch I would like to know what I need to get this working.

Comment: have you read this [MSDN: Static Classes and Static Class Memnbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I removed the static modifier from the WebDriver initialization it suddenly started working.

```
IWebDriver Edge = new EdgeDriver();
```

While I did not see any documentation that says we can't use a static instance, apparently we cannot.

Answer (score 0):

The same completely nondescript error occurs when there is already an instance of `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe` running.

Solution: Kill all corresponding instances first:

```
foreach (var process in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("MicrosoftWebDriver"))
{
    process.Kill();
}
```

(This happened to me using Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0)